# Events not showing in any view except Raw view?

Tags: google-analytics, zoho, crm

For some reason some events sent from a Zoho CRM extension via Measurement protocol don’t appear in any views besides raw view (and that copying filters to raw views doesn’t seem to make a difference).

Do you have any suggestions or ideas?
Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

A raw View should not have any filters applied to it (why it is a raw view).  The raw View ensures there is an unedited copy of all site data to refer to and analyze. An incorrectly configured filter, or incorrect filter order, on a Main reporting View, can result in unexpected changes/omissions in the View's data.

Keep in mind, filters are not retroactive, so do not change historical data in an existing View. It can also take up to 48hrs for new data coming into a View, to reflect changes once a filter is applied. Hence, why you may not be noticing any change when apply existing filters to the raw View.

You'll need to review what filters are currently applied to your other views, to work out what filter is removing the event data.

Follow best practices and create a test View for testing your filters.

Comment: Hi @Bronwyn V 

Thank you very much for the explanation. I am afraid this doesn't answer the question. 

Kind Regards,

Comment: That the raw View without filters is receiving all hits, suggests that there is a filter in play on your other views that is removing the data. What sort of filters do you have setup on the other views?

Comment: The filters are there to exclude some IP addresses. But, when I submit the form I am using another network.